# How do I transform these data into a stacked single table?

Tags: sas

I have a simple dataset that I would like in a single output table. I would like the variables 'age' and 'sex' stacked against a third variable, 'q16'. An example of the expected/needed output is attached below. I also need to weight the table values using the field 'weight'.

Have tried various versions of proc tabulate, freq, report, but have not come up with a solution. What I'm hoping to get out of this post is a fresh look on my problem and see if the community has any other solutions that I can try.

```
data survey;
   infile datalines dsd;
   input age : $20. sex : $10. q16 : $20. weight;
   datalines;
18 to 29,Male,VERY GOOD, 0.3984
46 to 64,Male,POOR, 1.6694
18 to 29,Female,POOR, 0.9696
46 to 64,Female,POOR, 0.6078
65 and over,Female,EXCELLENT, 1.0301
65 and over,Female,POOR, 0.7763
;
```

[needed layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oBJQm.png)

As you can see in the attached image, it's two variables stacked vertically, but I need those two by a third variable called 'q16'. At this point, I'm not looking for design as much as replicating the table in the image with weighted values.

Comment: Please update your question to include a text version of your needed layout.

Comment: See example 8 here https://support.sas.com/resources/papers/proceedings/pdfs/sgf2008/173-2008.pdf

Comment: Or this one which will create the table for a single group, not both though. https://gist.github.com/statgeek/2f27939fd72d1dd7d8c8669cd39d7e67

Answer (score 0):

`TABULATE` Procedure can produce all the numbers, however, there are no features for reporting multiple statistics in a single cell corresponding to a dimensional crossing -- each number gets it's own cell.

A variable that has statistics computed has to be specified in the `VAR` statement, and counts or percents are for `CLASS` variables.

For example:

```
data have;
  do person = 1 to 3218 + 1991;

    length status $5;
    status = ifc (ranuni(123) < 1991/(1991+3218), 'Dead', 'Alive');

    if ranuni(123) < 0.001 then age = .; else age = floor(28+35*ranuni(123));

    length gender $6;
    if status = 'Dead'
      then gender = ifc(ranuni(123) < 896 /(896+1095), 'Female', 'Male');
      else gender = ifc(ranuni(123) < 1977/(1977+1241), 'Female', 'Male');

    output;
  end;
run;

proc tabulate data=have;
  class status gender;
  var age;
  table
    age * (N NMISS MEAN STD MIN MAX MEDIAN QRANGE)
    gender * (N COLPCTN)
    , 
    status;
run;
```

[image]

To get the exact table in your image you could compute the results via one or more statistics procedures and produce the output table via `data _null_` and the `ODSOUT` component object.